# XSLT: how to match exact text value within an element and replace

Tags: xslt, textnode

I need to find a specific text value within a document,'method'and for each instance replace that text value 'method' with the following:

[element to replace method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KroKf.png)

This 'method' value can appear several times throughout the document. The issue is that I also need to retain the remaining text within the element, apart from 'method' which will be replaced.

```
      <section id="1">
        <title>Methods</title>
            <p>The test method blah has 6 types of methods available</p>
            <p>With the exception of a specific method<p
        </section>
     <section id="2">
        <title>Organisations</title>
            <p>The organisation has a method</p>
        </section>
```

I'm not sure if using fn:replace would the best approach, and if i also need to use regular expressions (something i'm not currently familiar with). Any advice on an approach here would be greatly appreciated.

Expected output only replaces the exact text 'method' with the content element, but retains 'methods':

```
<section id="1">
   <title>Methods</title>
   <p>The test <content type="description" xlink:href="linktodescription">method</named-content> blah has 6 types of methods available</p>
</section>     
<section id="2">
  <title>Organisations</title>
  <p>The organisation has a <content type="description" xlink:href="linktodescription">method</named-content></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show the expected output of the transformation and indicate clearly which instances of "method" need to be replaced and which do not. Also, post your code as code, not as pictures - and post it here, not in links.

Comment: You can't do a simple text replace for this, you'll need to insert an element.

Comment: (Shall `methods` be replaced, too? What about *methodical methodologists exploring methodists*?)

Comment: Apologies. To clarify 'method' exactly needs to be matched not 'methods' 'methodical' etc

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use? XSLT 2.0 with `xsl:analyze-string` can help but matching on word boundaries might require processor specific extension flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Saxon 9 as the XSLT processor you can use (based on http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/analyze-string.html)

```
<xsl:template match="section/p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\bmethod\b" flags=";j">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <content type="description" xlink:href="linktodescription">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </content>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```